# Events tab not showing in diagnostic tools VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

I was happily using VS2017 before my computer died.

In the diagnostic tools, when you stepped in the debugger, it would show you the time between steps. I'm pretty sure it did this under the Events tab.

In short.
What it should look like:
[image]

What it looks like now using my p.o.s VS2017 install on my new computer (that should be identical to the last one):

[image]

It was a mission just to get the Diagnostic Tools to show, I don't know how ive stuffed up my install so much.

How do I get the Events tab to show?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show what's inside the "summary" tab ? Because there should be a "Show events" option in there..
Also, which version of VS are you using now vs before your PC died ? (community / pro / another one... ?)